# Random GPS coordinates in a non rectangular space

Tags: google-maps, gps, random

I am working on an user interface that shows many pins on a map.
During the development I am randomly generating 1500 map pins just to be placed on the map to test look/feel/performance etc. issues.

The code which does that looks like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= 1500; i += 1) {
        $scope.mapPins.push({
            latitude: (Math.random() * 2) + 51,
            longitude: (Math.random() * 4) + 3,
            icon: themeImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * themeImages.length)],
            title: 'Sample title',
            infoContent: 'Sample content'
        });
    }
```

Naturally the area of the pins covered is a rectangle for latitudes 51-53 and longitudes 3-7. For those who are wondering where it is, it is the area roughly around Netherlands.

Now, there's a little problem that the Netherlands is not a rectangular area and a lot of these coordinates fall over the sea and I would like my coordinates to be only on the land.

**Is there a witty mathematical way how I can pool coordinates from a non-rectangular area?**

Of course I could make a google.maps polygon object that covers a nonrectangular shape and then via google api test every random generated pin whether it falls within the bounds of this shape etc, but that would be an overkill for UI design phase. Basically my question is whether there is a neat mathematical trick that would allow me to randomly generate coordinates from a non-rectangular space.

Answer (score 2):

Leave your code as it is, the rectangle is the bounding box over your area of interest.

Then add a line

```
if (isPointInpolygon(polygon, longitudeOrX, latitudeOrY) {
    // use this location
}
```

now you only need to search for a point in polygon function, which is easy to find.
you can directly use the coordinates in (long, lat) order, longitude is related to x coordinate, lat to y.
The polygon has to be filled with the coordinates of the country not insode the water.

If you have islands, then maybe you need multiple such polygons, then iterate over all.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be a stickler but you're actually generating 1501 map pins :)

It is very unlikely that you'll find a simpler solution than using a simple pointinpolygon check.

Use the Google Maps Drawing library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing#using_the_library) to draw a polygon around the boundary of the Netherlands  and save it however you want (e.g., in database, or just copy the string that defines the boundary's coordinates).

Then in your script above, define the google maps polygon (similar to what is done here in the official docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons), then use the containsLocation method in the Google Maps Geometry library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) to check if your random map pins lie within the boundaries of the Netherlands before adding them to the map.

For example:

```
    var netherlandsCoords = [
    // comma-separated list of coordinates defining the Netherlands boundary
    ];

    var netherlandsBoundary = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: netherlandsCoords
    });

    for (var i = 0; i <= 1500; i += 1) {
        var lat = (Math.random() * 2) + 51;
        var lng = (Math.random() * 4) + 3;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, netherlandsBoundary)) {
            $scope.mapPins.push({
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lng,
                icon: themeImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * themeImages.length)],
                title: 'Sample title',
                infoContent: 'Sample content'
            });
        } 
    }
```